# Is there a maximum Biotic Charge distance?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Biotic Charge for the Vanguard class lets you leap very quickly into distant enemies, and I've never not been able to perform the move on a target as long as I had a line-of-sight and my view was trained on them.

Is there a maximum distance to the charge, or can I safely assume that if I can target an enemy, I can hit them with a charge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The range is roughly the same as the maximum range at which you get a targeting frame/health bar for an enemy.

There are other factors that may prevent you from charging however, such as certain terrain obstacles or cover -  you'll need a clear line of sight for instance.

Comment: You also can't target enemies shooting at you from areas you can't walk on, such as distant catwalks, or enemy entry points. (Where Cerberus troops will rocket in from, for example)

Comment: @RavenDreamer so basically if I *could* reach an enemy, I can biotic charge them?

Comment: @BenBrocka Yup!